# Вывести данные в JSON через Express.js и Axios

Tags: node.js, express, axios

Не могу вывести данные в json формате: при вызове http://localhost:3000/ всегда пустые скобочки {}, а в вывод в консоль работает как надо.

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const axios = require('axios')

const app = express()

const getItems = async () => {
  const items = await axios
    .get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  return items.data.message
}

const logItems = async () => {
  const items = await getItems()
  console.log(items)
}

app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  logItems()
  res.json(getItems())
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере в функции отправки пропушена команда ожидания данных с `getItems()`. По факту вы передавали значение которого нет. Поправить можно так:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const data = await getItems();
  res.json(data);
})
```